# What is the expected result table during a SQL update trigger?

Tags: sql-server

During a SQL trigger update trigger is there an easy way to get the whole expected result table (that is, what the table would look like after the trigger executes?)

Here's the only thing I could think of (which boils down to the table MINUS the deleted table + the inserted table):

```
SELECT *
FROM TheTable t
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM DELETED d 
        WHERE 
            d.primaryKey1 = t.primaryKey1
        AND d.primaryKey2 = t.primaryKey2 
        -- ...
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM INSERTED
```

**UPDATE:**

The above is unnecessarily complicated inside of a FOR/AFTER trigger.  It suffices just to query the table itself.  (Thanks to @usr for the wake-up call.)  However, for an instead of trigger you would do something similar to get the resulting table, although it's likely you would actually want to be constructing the table during it's execution.

Comment: @RyanVincent: The problem I'm trying to solve is one of ensuring that there be at most one row meeting a certain criteria in the table.  I'm pretty sure the only safe way to do that is with a trigger since a check constraint with a UDF could potentially have issues on multi-insert / multi-update statements.

Comment: What about an AFTER trigger?

Comment: @RyanVincent: I was going to say it should have at most 1 row, so if it finds 2 or more it should fail, otherwise succeed.

Comment: @usr: I actually was using a FOR trigger already, which I think is the same thing as the AFTER trigger.  Are you saying I don't need to do all this extra work and just query the table?

Comment: Don'T ask me, look at the documentation. I'm not that familiar with triggers.

Comment: @usr: you might actually be right.  *facepalm*.  I'll investigate and update as needed.

Comment: @usr: Man I hada  major misconception there.  I just added a select *, 'trigger' as trig to my trigger and ran it, and it looks like the table I'm querying is the candidate table.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `AFTER` trigger to look at the table in the final state.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested you can use an after insert/update trigger. In this trigger context you have the table with the new values, but the insert or update is not really over, so any throw will rollback the operation. Example:

```
-- drop table testConstraint
create table testConstraint
(
    Id INT,
    Name varchar(10)

    -- CONSTRAINT CK_testConstraint_misc CHECK (dbo.checkTest(Id, Name) <> 0)
)

create TRIGGER trgConstraint 
ON dbo.testConstraint
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM testConstraint where Id > 10)
        THROW 51000, 'Invalid record found', 1;
END
GO

-- ok
insert into testConstraint (Id, Name) values (1, 'n1'), (2, 'n2'), (3, 'n3')
go
select * from testConstraint
go

-- will fail
insert into testConstraint values (11, 'n11')
go
select * from testConstraint
GO

-- will fail
update testConstraint set Id = 20 where Id = 2
go
select * from testConstraint
GO
```